# How to not flip the coin until the button is pressed? Python GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently making a coin flipping simulator with GUI. When I run the code, the program shows a random object of my list in a `tkinter.Label()`, and as I press the button, nothing happens. I want that at first no text is visible and if I press the button, it will choose a random object of the list.
So here's my code:

```
#import mudules
import random, sys, tkinter
random.seed()
main = tkinter.Tk()
main.title("Coin flipping simulator")
main.geometry("300x200")

#list
options = ["Head", "Number"]

def flip():
    coin = random.choice(options)
    text = tkinter.Label(text = coin)
    text.pack()

buttonFlip = tkinter.Button(main, command=flip(), text="Flip coin!")

buttonFlip.pack()
buttonFlip.place(x=150, y=100, anchor="center")

#end
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
buttonFlip = tkinter.Button(main, command=flip(), text="Flip coin!")
```

This executes the flip function try:

```
buttonFlip = tkinter.Button(main, command=flip, text="Flip coin!")
```

Comment: Yes, works! Thank you!